# onenote api beta - patch method not support id attribute on tag paragraph

Tags: onenote

i use onenote patch method API  (beta),

send the body :

```html
[{
  'target': 'body',
  'action': 'append',
  'content': '<p id="item1">test</p>'
}]
```

and the result is :

```html
<p lang="en-US">test</p>
```

where is the attribute ID ?

is patch method not support id attribute for tag paragraph ?

it seems work for tag img

thx,
Edwin

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble! This looks like a bug in the beta-page recall feature where we are missing ids on some of the page elements like paragraphs and tables. We are fixing it now and will reply back once the issue is fixed.

Thanks and sorry for the any inconvenience caused!

Comment: patch and inquiry content API is very interesting. the API give lots creativity option. please inform when it ready, maybe i can customize notes based on the API. thx